# stuck on starting app and after started mongodb is not connecting

Tags: meteor

I have installed meteor. On command prompt while creating an app the command is stuck on starting app. Following are the steps which I done

- mkdir meteor
- cd meteor
- meteor create todo
- cd todo
- meteor

after this output shows as below

- started proxy
- starting your app

after that I have add set URL for mongo dB 
as shown below:

*c:/users/om/meteor/todo> set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017*

after that I used meteor command

the output is as shown below

- started proxy
- app is started

after creating app meteor is not connecting to the mongodb and does not show after proxy that started mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my-database-name
```

You'll notice that I added a database name at the end, which is probably what you are missing.

Comment: I used your solution it shows 'export' is not recognized as as an internal or external command,operable programming or batch file

Comment: Oh, are you on Windows? Then set is fine :)

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 10.

Comment: Did adding the database name fix it?